# Sony Vegas: Make timeline "line" follow event trimming?

Tags: video-editor, editing, vegas-pro

It would be a huge time saver to make the time "line" actively chase the end point dragging of events, so you can tell precisely where the event is compared to other tracks above and below.

Is this possible?

[image: Explained]

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what your use case is. I am normally dragging events' end points IN the timeline, so of course the timeline and other tracks and events are visible. You also get magnetic snapping to other events if you want. Am I getting your question wrong?

Comment: Ideally the timeline "line" should move along with the endpoint of the event, so you can precisely know where it's positioning. Take for example subtitles, if the timeline line would follow the event you could drag the text-event without guessing exactly where it's compared to the speech patterns in the audio track. Right now I have to drag and guess, then click the endpoint of the media-event to see the "line" in that position.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible in Vegas to move the "timeline" line (cursor) along with your edit.

You can, however, set the cursor directly to where you want your event to end by just clicking to that position. Then drag your event to the cursor and let it snap magnetically to it.

This way you dont have to manually set and delete any markers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Vegas specifically, but does it have any kind of mark feature?  The traditional solution to this is to apply 3 point edit techniques and scrub to set your points.

If you aren't familiar with 3 point editing, it consists of determining 3 out of 4 points, the beginning of your edit on the source, the end of your edit on the source, the beginning of your clip that you are bringing in and the end of the clip you are bringing in.  If you know 3 of these, you can determine the forth and complete your edit.

For example, with a subtitle, I would scrub the source video to find the start and end point of the subtitle.  I would place a marker at each of those frames and would then add the subtitle between the two markers.  This general technique should work with just about any reasonable editor and it sounds like it will address your workflow problem.

Comment: Sounds elegant and can be done, but in practice putting a marker before dragging becomes another step and cleaning markers after each event drag is a drag. Let's see if anyone knows a different workaround. Thank you.